# iOS Splash Fade Shrinking Thingy

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, fade, splash-screen

I finally figured out how to fade the splash screen out, but it shrinks it to 640x920 right before doing so. Here's a vid: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUXrq-uHlVk

Anybody know how to fix this? Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UIImageView *splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:splash];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     splash.alpha = 0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [splash removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the default.png is a screenshot, however you will need to set the status bar on your "splash" subview to hidden.

Comment: How can I do that? I tried "Status bar initially hidden" in the Plist, but then it never comes back.

Comment: i think it is [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;

Comment: Same problem, status bar never comes back. I know apps can do it with the status bar, i.e. alienblue

Comment: did you turn it back on after the fade is complete. i.e. [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;

Comment: You can animate the status bar so it slides in. However if you do not want that disruption, Why not add a "fake" status bar to the default.png. that way once that image fades out, you have the real status bar underneath.

Answer (score 0):

The "Default.png" is a screenshot from your device or emulator, because of this it contains your status bar... it looks like the image is being offset by that much... you might try using a different named image that is identical without the status bar.

Comment: It's not a screen shot, but I do have a black bar at the top of the image. Using one without a black bar does the same thing, and I believe the image is being "smushed" not shifted down.